# PHP Session not saving/storing

Tags: php

For a project, I am creating a web app, in which, login will be a paramount part. Unfortunately, I seem to be unable to get sessions to work properly, so the sign-ins do not last at all.
Here is some simple code I wrote on my [Testing/experimentation/debugging page.](http://alexandstein.com/Testing/)

Here is the head of the testing page.

```
<? 
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start(); 
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
```

Here is the code which uses session data.

```
$_SESSION[0] = $_SESSION[0] + 1;
echo($_SESSION[0]);
```

It's supposed to increment with each, visit, but it hasn't been doing so, as with the login system.

Here is session setting from the `phpinfo()` function if it helps.

```
Session Support enabled
Registered save handlers    files user sqlite
Registered serializer handlers  php php_binary wddx

Directive   Local Value Master Value 
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.bug_compat_42   On  On
session.bug_compat_warn On  On
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly Off Off
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.entropy_file    no value    no value
session.entropy_length  0   0
session.gc_divisor  100 100
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
session.gc_probability  1   1
session.hash_bits_per_character 4   4
session.hash_function   0   0
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   /tmp    /tmp
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.use_cookies On  On
session.use_only_cookies    On  On
session.use_trans_sid   0   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the !isset to check your session, just call session_start(); at the top of any page that deals with the session variable.

Keys at the root level must be valid identifiers, so session[1] wouldn't work, but session['1'] would.

[Session documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) there's some interesting qualifiers.

There's also some more advanced examples in the comments:
If you don't have control of the register_globals setting: (isset($_REQUEST['_SESSION'])).

Comment: Ah, thank you! That was the problem it seems. I wasn't using a string identify and was using numeric indices instead. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the [PHP session_start Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php):

> session_start() creates a session or resumes the current one based on a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a cookie.

So to use cookie based session you should always call `session_start()` at the beginning of every script to resume the current session. Don't check for `$_SESSION`, PHP will not start a new session but resume the current one.

Answer (score 0):

I set my sessions up like this- (it is secure and works for me)

on the log in page:

```
$_SESSION['fingerprint'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . PHRASE . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

// or simply `$_SESSION['fingerprint'] = $login['id']` // stores ID as session (insecure)

(phrase defined on a config page)

then on the header that is throughout the rest of the site:

```
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['fingerprint'] != md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . PHRASE . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {       
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: http://website login page/');
    exit();     
}
```

and then use your `session['fingerprint']`

Comment: Why is storing the id in the session insecure?

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate your question a little.If you got problem with session not existing on multiple page then you might not be calling session on each page.Every page which works after Logging-in must have session called separately as far as I know

Comment: This should have been a comment.